# Regular expression not matching url as expected

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to match different urls to MVC actions of my controller.

Here is the current expression i'm testing:

```
#^/products((/([0-9]+)-([0-9a-z\_]+))*(/(index\.(html|pdf|xml|json))?)?)?$#i
```

When i try to match this to:

```
/products/22-test/25-test2
```

I was expecting to get (via preg_match_all) the following results:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "/products/22-test/25-test2"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "/22-test"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "22"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "test"
  [4]=>
  string(17) "/25-test"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "25"
  [6]=>
  string(5) "test2"
}
```

But instead i get

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "/products/22-test/25-test2"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "/22-test/25-test2"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "/25-test2"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "25"
  [4]=>
  string(5) "test2"
}
```

**UPDATE**

The problem is that i'm not getting the category list translated into individual elements just so that i make my problem as clear as possible...

I'm using `(/([0-9]+)-([0-9a-z\_]+))*` in an attempt to transform as many category identifiers into a parsed item. Thats why i used `(...)*`, it should allow any number of categories to be matches and should match each of them no?

**UPDATE 2**

It seems that if i update the regexp to support many times the same category identifier, it gets parsed, i was hoping that `(...)*` would parse it many times instead of giving me one big list of category identifiers.

For example, this works fine:

```
#^/products((/([0-9]+)-([0-9a-z\_]+))?(/([0-9]+)-([0-9a-z\_]+))?(/([0-9]+)-([0-9a-z\_]+))?(/([0-9]+)-([0-9a-z\_]+))?(/([0-9]+)-([0-9a-z\_]+))?(/(index\.(html|pdf|xml|json))?)?)?$#i
```

But forces me to repeat the category selector MANY times. So if i have a client that decides to put more than X categories in his catalog, i'm blocked and the urls won't resolve correctly...

Is there any way to support that?

Comment: `#^/products((/([0-9]+)-([0-9a-z\_\-]+))*(/(index\.(html|pdf|xml|json))?)?)?$#i` Try That

Comment: Nope, i tried it anyway although i was sure the \- wouldnt change it. The problem is that i'm not getting the category list translated into individual elements

Comment: Darn i think i found it... i have to repeat the category selector many times. So i have to hope that my clients will never use more than X categories deep or it will stop working... Is there any other way?

Comment: You're using repetition on a subpattern, so the subpattern match will only be populated with the last match, as it is overwritten in each successive repetition.

Comment: Does it have to be done in a single regex operation? If not, you could match the entire part between "products" and the page name, then split that string on slashes.

Comment: Why are you even using regular expression, why not use `str_split` on `/` and then re-split in `-`?

Comment: Using regular expressions to detect which controller and action to use from the router and parse the data at the same time, but i think i'll have to do it in a two step fashion in all cases, thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a *positional* result. I.e. Position 1 captures the first `()`, position 2 captures the second set of `()`.

A `*` makes the capture group *larger*, but doesn't multiply the positions.

You might want to just *split* the first group using a "findall" with `(/([0-9]+)-([0-9a-z\_]+))` in a second step.

Comment: Apart from repeating the selector, is there any other way to achieve what i want?

Comment: Yes. `findAll` on the first group with the regular expression of the first group only.

Comment: ok.... shucks... changes my route object substantially i think, i'll have to review that. I'll wait to see if there are other solutions that might popup but that seems the only one so far...

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code to get individual categories id and name:

```
$str = '/products/22-test/25-test2';
if (stripos($str, "/products/") !== false &&
    preg_match_all('#(/(\d+)-([a-z\d_-]+))#i', $str, $m))
   print_r($m);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /22-test
            [1] => /25-test2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 22
            [1] => 25
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => test
            [1] => test2
        )

)
```

Comment: It would work with your solution but won't in my case cause i use a match to detect which action i need to execute and detect the sub information at the same time.

Comment: You could do something like `if (stripos($str, "/products/") !== false && preg_match_all('#(/(\d+)-([a-z\d_-]+))#i', $str, $m))` as in my updated answer as well.